# TypeError: callback is not a function when executing a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, coffeescript, requestjs

I'm trying to run a callback when the `end` event is fired by a stream in coffee-script. On attempting to run my code, I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\Gum-Joe\Documents\Projects\retisci\lib\downloader.js:45
    callback();
    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
  at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gum-Joe\Documents\Projects\retisci\lib\downloader.js:45:5)
  at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
  at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gum-Joe\Documents\Projects\retisci\node_modules\request\request.js:988:12)
  at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
  at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

**NB:** Output modified to protect my full name.

Here is my code:

```
###
# Downloader
# @param url {String} url to GET
# @param save {String} Save file
# @param options {Object} Options
# @param callback {Function} Callback
###
downloader.get = (url, save, options, logger_options, callback) ->
  log = require('single-line-log').stdout
  # Download
  # Logger
  logger = new Logger('retis', logger_options)
  # File stream
  file_stream = fs.createWriteStream(save)
  log("#{"[retis INFO]".green} Downloading #{url}...0% at 0 kb/sec...\n")
  progress(request(url))
    .on('progress', (state) ->
      percent = "#{Math.floor(state.percentage * 100)}% [#{Math.round(state.size.transferred / 1024)} kb of #{Math.round(state.size.total / 1024)} kb]"
      log("#{"[retis INFO]".green} Downloading #{url}...#{percent} at #{Math.round(state.speed / 1024)} kb/sec...\n")
    )
    .on('data', (d) ->
      file_stream.write d
      return
    )
    .on 'error', (e) ->
      callback(e)
      return
    .on 'end', () ->
      log("#{"[retis INFO]".green} Downloading #{url}...100%\n")
      logger.info("Downloaded #{url}.\n")
      # This is what causes the error
      callback()
      return
  return
```

Running the callback at the start of the function works, running it at the end of the function works, but running it in the `end` event's callback doesn't.

Could someone please suggest how to fix this bug in my code?

**NB:** You can find all the code at https://github.com/jakhu/retis-ci in the file src/downloader.coffee. Feel free to look at the other files, in case this bug relates to them.

Comment: How are you calling `downloader.get`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 56 of the unpacker.coffee file you are calling the get method with one param less than expected:

```
get(data.url, file_save, @download_options, (err) ->
```

The correct method signature looking like this:

```
get(url, save, options, logger_options, callback)
```

That - of course - leads to the last param (callback) to be undefined.

Comment: Hi, just found this issue in my code - silly me for assuming only `src/plugins.coffee` called it. Thanks for your help anyway!